# to dismiss a viewcontroller using collectionView cell

Tags: swift

i am having a difficulty on dismissing a viewController when i click a collectionviewcell. so my collectionview is placed inside a uiview that is then displayed in a viewcontroller. whenever the user click on collectionViewCell, i want the view to trigger bye() function that is placed inside the viewcontroller. i add print("bye") just to see if it work, and it does print the word but it does not execute `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` to dismiss the viewcontroller along with the uiview and collectionview. why it does not dismiss the controller? is there another way that i can do the same thing? here is the code :

the view controller

```
class sideViewController: UIViewController {

    let dismissBtn:UIButton = {
       let content = UIButton()
        content.backgroundColor = .green
        content.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bye), for: .touchUpInside)
        return content
    }()

    let sideTableViews: sideCollectionView = {
       let content = sideCollectionView()
        return content
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dismissBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sideTableViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(dismissBtn)
        view.addSubview(sideTableViews)

        dismissBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        dismissBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        dismissBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:40).isActive = true
        dismissBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

        sideTableViews.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dismissBtn.bottomAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        sideTableViews.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        sideTableViews.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        sideTableViews.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func membershipController(){
        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "membershipViewController") as! membershipViewController
        self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func bye(){
        print("bye")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

this is the collectionView code and the uiview

```
class sideCollectionView:UIView, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    let arrayLbl = ["connection","achievement","template","setting"]
    let arrayImg = ["connection","achievement","template","setting"]
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayLbl.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! sideCollectionViewCell
        cell.titleImg.image = UIImage(named: "\(arrayImg[indexPath.row])")
        cell.titleLbl.text = arrayLbl[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (self.frame.width / 2) - 40, height: (self.frame.width / 2) - 40)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(25, 25, 10, 25)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            connectController()
            print("connection")
            let side = sideViewController()
            side.bye()
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            let side = sideViewController()
            side.bye()
            print("achievement")
        }
        if indexPath.row == 2{
            let side = sideViewController()
            side.bye()
            print("template")
        }
        if indexPath.row == 3{
            let side = sideViewController()
            side.bye()
            print("setting")
        }
    }

    lazy var collectionViews: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews(){
        collectionViews.register(sideCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionViews.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        addSubview(collectionViews)
        collectionViews.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionViews.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionViews.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionViews.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionViews.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc func connectController(){
        let side = sideViewController()
        side.bye()
    }

    @objc func settingController(){
        let side = sideViewController()
        side.bye()
    }

    @objc func achievementController(){
        let side = sideViewController()
        side.bye()
    }

    @objc func templateController(){
        let side = sideViewController()
        side.bye()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this

```
 let side = sideViewController()
```

is another instance other than the displayed one , so add this var to the view

```
class sideCollectionView:UIView {
  var currentVc:sideViewController?

}
```

//

when you create the variable assign it

```
lazy var sideTableViews: sideCollectionView = {
   let content = sideCollectionView()
   content.currentVc = self
   return content
}()
```

//

Inside

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        connectController()
        print("connection")
        currentVc?.bye()
    }
}
```

Comment: i got this error on content.currentVc = self           |||||||  Cannot assign value of type '(sideViewController) -> () -> (sideViewController)' to type 'sideViewCont

Comment: thank you it work :). what is lazy do btw? its new to me